# PHP why use "echo" in action

Tags: php, forms, echo

Is there any special reason to use this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

I am learning php, but I really don't get why do you have to use the "echo" here. We do not need to print or show the variable $_SERVER, it is more like an internal code. So are there any rules regarding when to using the "echo" for php scripts ?

Comment: Using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` isn't recommended and should be avoided.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Why? Aren't the issues avoided using htmlspecialchars()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is a superglobal that returns the name of the currently running script.  So if that form is on index.php than the php server is going to echo `index.php`.

There are really no rules as to when to use `echo`.  The only time you can't use it is on an array.   If you attempt to use it on an array it will return the object rather than the string.  For an array you can either iterate through it printing every object, `var_dump(array)`, or `print array[0]` and if it's a dictionary `print array['key']`  The most important thing to remember with php is that after all the processing is done all it does is sends the browser a plain html file.

Comment: That's not completely true because an array can only be sown by using `print_r()` . If you would use echo for an array you will end up with an error.

Comment: @SuperDJ That's wrong, you will end up with `Array`, if the variable is an array. But `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is a string.

Comment: @SuperDJ , changed it to add you can't that you can't print an array.

Comment: But do I really need the "echo" on the action, because the global variable will get the name of the running script, and that's all I need, no need to print it or do I really need to "print" the value, I tested it and it works without the echo, or maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: @FraK No, it would work without the echo.  The reason it would work without the echo is doing: 
`<form method="post" action="">` 
submits to the current page.  For example if your page was called index.php doing  `<form method="post" action="">`, `<form method="post" action="index.php">` and `<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">` are all the same thing.

Comment: Ok, but in general, there is no need to use "echo" when calling a function, if you are not going to display its value on the browser right ?

Answer (score 1):

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] pertains to the current executing document/path. For example, index.php. Using echo just prints that path into the action attribute of the form which means that the form will be submitted to index.php.

Comment: This is the best answer I've found. Thanks for the clear and concise explanation!